# How to launch app when bluetooth beacon fired?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

I have a beacon that have 3 different bluetooth signals;

> 1.Button Clicked:   UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX (same)   Minor: 1   Major: 1
>
> 2.Button Clicked:   UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX (same)   Minor: 2   Major: 2
>
> 3.Button Clicked:   UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX (same)   Minor: 3   Major: 3

When I click the buttons on my beacon, I want to launch my application if the application is terminated. For this situation I added CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate and CLLocationManagerDelegate to view controller.

Firstly, I enter the view and pair my beacon successfully;

```
// MARK: - Peripheral Delegate
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    if(peripheral.services == nil)
        return;
    
    for(CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        if([service.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:@"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"]) {
            [self startMonitoringIBeaconRegionsWithUUID:service.UUID.UUIDString];
            [centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
        }
    }
}
```

```
// MARK: - iBeacon
-(void)startMonitoringIBeaconRegionsWithUUID: (NSString *)iBeaconUUIDString {
    NSUUID *iBeaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:iBeaconUUIDString];

    
    self.emergencyIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@-1", iBeaconUUIDString];
    CLBeaconRegion *regionEmergency = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithUUID:iBeaconUUID major:(CLBeaconMajorValue)1 minor:(CLBeaconMinorValue)1 identifier:self.emergencyIdentifier];

    [regionEmergency setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
    [regionEmergency setNotifyOnExit:YES];
    // regionEmergency.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = NO;

    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionEmergency];
}
```

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion: forRegion: %@", region.identifier);
    if (![region.identifier isEqualToString:self.emergencyIdentifier])
        return;

    // Launch the app and go to view...
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sg_emergency" sender:self];
}
```

But when I close the application; Even if I click the 1st button, the didEnterRegion method never works and does not launch the application. I also tried sending notification to the user, because the method is not triggered, it does not send notifications either. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your design here. If you never leave the 1/1 (major/minor) region, then you're unlikely to get another "entered region" notification for it (it might work sometimes, but you can't rely on it). iBeacons changing their major/minor values doesn't cause the device to leave a region (certainly not quickly). iBeacon is a location service, not a data-transmit service. The way to overcome this problem is to use a BLE connection and subscribe to a characteristic that gets updated (using `setNotifyValue`)  rather than iBeacon.

Comment: I suggest you create three different CLBeaconRegion objects, one for each major/minor combination and monitor all three.